# Integration two Fedex account in Magento

Tags: magento, fedex

We are looking in Magento having the option to integrate the Fedex account based on the user location. We want to use the two Fedex account in our Magento store.

Can any one give some solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

At my company we ran into a similar problem: provide shipping rates through two different FedEx accounts based on the country of origin.

My solution was something along the lines of:

1. Create a module to extend Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Fedex.
2. Add the account information for the second FedEx account through the system.xml of the new module.
3. Rewrite the setRequest model to load the relevant account data based on whatever criteria you wanted to apply.

That way the calls were directed to specific accounts and were transparent to both the front and back-end users.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it worked. In our context we were able to offer different shipping rates under different accounts to non-US and US customers.

Answer (score -1):

@Kalvin Klien Here is the repo for the sample code: https://viribus.kilnhg.com/Code/Repositories/Public/Fedex-Alt

The code is not complete and is just to demonstrate how to extend the model and create the secondary configuration data. You will need to create the name space/module to let Magento know that are you extending Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Abstract.